# remote zsh doesn't print in 256 color though terminal can print

Tags: bash, terminal, colors, zsh

[image]

I want to print my remote Zsh print in 256 color. But as you can see, terminal itself can print all colors, Zsh theme only prints in 8 the color version.

Test codes here:

```
curl -s https://gist.githubusercontent.com/HaleTom/89ffe32783f89f403bba96bd7bcd1263/raw/ | bash
```

I installed `oh-my-zsh` and `agnoster` theme. It should print like this: [image: this]

I accessed remote server with PuTTy. Terminal type string is `xterm-256color`.

I also tried putting `TERM=xterm-256color` in `.zshrc`.

Where should I look to fix this problem?